# MSSQL Long polling | Is calling database in while loop for new information safe?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, database, pdo

Imagine you were starting a site that will grow to millions of users in a year. I understand that you can load balance your servers to keep thing speedy, but my question is this :
Using the long polling method for creating a live chat system and updating content on the users timeline, you give a request to a php file on the server, and call the database each cycle through the while loop while looking for new data, correct? If so, isn't that WAYYY too many times to be calling a database? Thanks.

Comment: I believe polling for millions of users is expensive. take a look at this link. it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219532/how-does-in-browser-chat-work

Comment: @FLICKER Then what would you recommend? I would rather not go through the hassle of installing and learning lots of different plugins/languages. From what I know, facebook uses this method, right? How are they able to do it so well?

Comment: @FLICKER Everyone in that post was referring to comet, which is basically what I was talking about implementing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have experience in chat in web platform. I had implemented a chat system using UDP but in web is different story. I just found that link and thought might be useful.