# Live actualization of notifications/data inside the site

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, notifications, chat

I want to try to make a chat system using php, ajax, databases and I`ve been curious how they make (for example) the online/offline status (notifications, messages) actualize, do they just refresh the code every second? or is there a sneaky way of not running a script every second

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219537/2996989) might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about websockets and socket.io .
Ajax is powerful but is not meant for the purpose you are looking for.